# Caching set-like collection

Tags: java, caching, collections, set

I'm trying to cache a lot of similar values with only set-like requirements. Unfortunately `Set<?>` allows me only to check whether an element exists inside - it won't give the existing element back to me. What I'd like to do is:

```
Element e = receiveSomeElement();
e = elements.cache(e);
// now e is either the original e, or one that was already in the cache
doSomeWorkOn(e);
```

I could probably simulate that with `SortedSet` and getting `.subSet(e, e)`, but it seems like waste of time to keep the set sorted. I could also use `HashMap<Element, Element>` and store the same referrence as the key and value, but that seems just as dirty...

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: go with the hashmap only, that is only way you can implement caching

Comment: Why do you want to do this? When will you purge elements from the cache? How do you want to do that? You might want to consider using WeakReferences in the cache.

Comment: I ended up writing `ObjectCache<E> implements Set<E>` with a `WeakHashMap<E, WeakReference<E>>` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a HashSet, the underlying implementation actually uses a HashMap anyway, so I suggest you go with a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [LRUMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap.html) provided by Apache Collections. It behaves like a Map, but limits the size so that things don't go out of hands when processing large amount of data. I also wrote an article on how to add some bookkeeping around the LRUMap to make it also shrink when not utilized: [Blog post: Caching without Crashing](http://softwareengineeringcorner.blogspot.com/2012/01/java-caching-without-crashing.html)

Answer (score 0):

below is the basic caching implemetation here also HashMap is used 
[Caching implementation](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/perf4.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use LinkedHashMap so you can implement a simple eviction policy.

```
Map<Element, Element> cache = new LinkedHashMap<Element, Element>(16, 0.7, true){
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Element, Element> eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_SIZE;
    }

    public Element get(Object key) {
        Element element = super.get(key);
        // put if not present.
        if (element == null) {
            element = (Element) key;
            super.put(element, element)
        }
        return element;
    }
};
```

This way you can call get(e) and it will return e if its not present.  It is limited to MAX_SIZE by removing the least recently used entry as required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. Not claiming I would solve it like this. See it as a demonstration on how to get hold of an specific element in a set.

```
// Create a temporary copy of the cache.
Set<Element> matches = new HashSet<Element>(cache);

// Remove all elements that don't equal the soughtElement.
matches.retainAll(Collections.singleton(soughtElement));

if (matches.isEmpty()) {
    // ... not found
} else {
    Element found = matches.iterator().next();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That looks like a lot of copying on every cache() call if you have 10k+ elements in the set...

Comment: Yep. A `O(n)` solution, when you can get away with `O(1)` by using a map :P